# How i can edit php.ini from cpanel when php.ini is readonly

Tags: php, cpanel

How i can edit php.ini file from cpanel.I am using putty and vi editor to access php.ini file.It showing  message -> 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override) .If php.ini is readonly then how i can change its permissions.

Regards
Deepak

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is more suited for http://serverfault.com and I have voted to move it there. After five people vote, it will move automatically.

Comment: If this question is moved, just follow the link that appears in the "Migrated to" box. No need to re-ask your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the permissions of a file with `chmod`. You can only change the permissions if you're the file owner; if you're not the file owner then you must log in as the owner to edit the file or to change its permissions.